# Flattened Array with Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm certain this question is very common, but I can't seem to find a robust answer for my use case.

I have an Array of objects with nesting in two levels. Here is an example of the array:

```
let array = [
{ company: 'CompanyName1',
    child: [
        { title: 'title1a',
        baby: [
            { title: 'title1ab' },
            { title: 'title1abc' }
        ]
        },
        { title: 'title2a',
        baby: [
            { title: 'titleb2abcd' },
            { title: 'titleb2abcde' }
        ]
        }           
    ]
},
{ company: 'CompanyName2',
    child: [
        { title: 'title2b',
        baby: [
            { title: 'titleb3ab' },
            { title: 'titleb3abc' }
        ]
        }        
    ]
}
]
```

And this is my expected Array:

```
    let newArray = [
    { 
     company: 'companyName1',
     child_title_0: 'title1a',
     child_title_1: 'title1a', 
     child_baby_0: 'title1ab',
     child_baby_1: 'title1abc',
     child_baby_2: 'title1abcd',
     child_baby_3: 'title1abcde',  
    },
    { 
     company: 'companyName2',
     child_title_0: 'title2b',
     child_baby_0: 'titleb3ab',
     child_baby_1: 'titleb3abc',
    }
    ]
```

Basically I need to flatten each of the top level objects of the array. Since the nested objects have the same keys (follow a model, and are dynamic -- some items have 10 nested objects, some 0, etc.) I have to dynamically generate each of the new keys, possibly based in the index of the loops.

Any help -- direction is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the correction -- it's been edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the map function to return a manipulated version of each object in the array.

```js
let results = [
  { 
    company: 'CompanyName1',
    child: [
        { 
          title: 'title1a',
          baby: [
            { title: 'title1ab' },
            { title: 'title1abc' }
          ]
        },
        { 
          title: 'title2a',
          baby: [
            { title: 'titleb2abcd' },
            { title: 'titleb2abcde' }
          ] 
        }           
    ]
  },
  { 
    company: 'CompanyName2',
    child: [
        { 
          title: 'title2b',
          baby: [
            { title: 'titleb3ab' },
            { title: 'titleb3abc' }
          ]
        }        
    ]
  }
];

let flattened = results.map(company => {
  let childCount = 0, babyCount = 0;
  company.child.forEach(child => {
    company['child_title_'+childCount] = child.title;
    child.baby.forEach(baby => {
      company['child_baby_'+babyCount] = baby.title;
      babyCount++;
    });
    childCount++;
  });
  delete company.child;
  return company;
});

console.log(flattened);
```

Comment: As per the question, this needs to be recursive because the nested objects can be `n` levels deep.

Comment: @mhodges Its easy to misunderstand *Basically I need to flatten each of the top level objects of the array* - perhaps add a 'recursively flatten'.

Comment: Thank you everybody ! Recursively Flatten makes more sense as well. This answer worked for me with minor adjustments to my real data model.

Comment: @mmarquez Can you give me an example of a more nested model that would actually require a recursive parse? I'll update my answer if so